# Why isn't Markdown applied in comments?

Tags: support, comments, markdown

I've been trying for 15 minutes to figure out why my Markdown content won't work until I realized I was typing in the comments to an answer, not an actual answer. After a quick look around, I didn't see any Markup content in comments. Is this a bug or a "feature"?

Comment: Markdown *like* `what`?

Comment: While this doesn't fully answer your question, if you click "help" next to the comment box while typing a comment, you'll see what select markdown _does_ work in comments. (And get a link to the help page about it.)

Comment: not _all_ the features available in answer section will be there in comments. It isnt really necessary IMO. You _could_ try opening a feature request if you feel you need a particular one

Comment: ***Unsupported Markdown Detected***

Answer (score 11):

As explained [on this help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), comments can use a subset of Markdown, but not all of what is available for questions and answers.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question isn't asking if markdown isn't being applied on comments, but why it is that formatting isn't used on comments. "I didn't see any markup in comments" is a dead giveaway.

Comment: @Braiam It's an untrue premise, and this answer corrects it.

Comment: @deceze Again, the OP isn't asking why formatting isn't available on comments, it is why "I don't see any markup in comments", or why isn't formatting being used on comments, to which the actual answer is "because comments are only meant to be clarification or pointing out problems".

Comment: @Braiam I'm not sure what you're saying. Markup  ***is***  supported in comments. Likely OP simply didn't use the correct supported subset and hence didn't see any…?!

Comment: @Braiam But [some] markdown *is* applied to comments.  So that argument is based on a false premise, and thus isn't sound.  If that were true then *why is markdown in fact applied to comments*?

Comment: @Braiam Considering the OP was trying to use markdown in comments, it seems very clear to me that their intention is to find out why markdown is not _usable_ in comments, which is indeed a false premise. What they didn't see was that markdown was supported, it was just worded sub-optimally.

Comment: @Braiam If nothing else, this answer at least makes it clear it is not a bug but rather intended behaviour, which is something explicitly asked in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Markup is INDEED available in comments; the OP missed the reasonably obvious `help` link right under the `Add Comment` button that appears for EVERY comment box, which explains that there is only a limited set of markdown that applies to comments.

As to why the OP didn't see markup in comments, I would guess that I the OP didn't look hard enough.

And yes, I can be that obnoxious; **I** am the OP. :-)

Comment: I wonder what you kind of formatting you needed, then. Indenting a code fragment with four spaces? Inlining an image? Adding a numbered list?

Comment: I was reading this and thinking wow, that's a bit rude to the OP. *I can be that obnoxious; I am the OP. :-)* You made me smile :)

Comment: @usr2564301 - exactly - I wanted to type in some code.

Comment: @YvetteColomb - If you can't laugh at yourself...